# Dukt Twitter plugin float issue

Tags: plugins, plugin-dukttwitter

I'm using the dukt.net Twitter plugin, in a Matrix field. It works fine locally, but on our dev server, something odd is happening, when I enter a Tweet url, like:

```
https://twitter.com/POLITICOEurope/status/596249628892364800
```

It fetches the tweet from the API correctly, but then displays it in the CP and in the templates as:

```
https://twitter.com/POLITICOEurope/status/5.96249628892E+17
```

So it converts it to a float. However, in the "fields_tweets_tweet" field in the database, it lists the correct long ID: 596249628892364800

And the odd thing is that it's happening on the dev server, but not locally. Anyone an idea where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure PHP is interpreting that string as an `int`. Doing a `var_dump` on the variable shows `int(596249628892364800)`. That's pretty much PHP's type casting at work.

While you could cast the variable as a string, there's actually an unused variable called `id_str` which is ideal to use.

Edit the file `twitter\fieldtypes\Twitter_TweetFieldType.php`. Replace line 48 from:

```
$url = 'https://twitter.com/'.$tweet['user']['screen_name'].'/status/'.$tweet['id'];
```

To:

```
$url = 'https://twitter.com/'.$tweet['user']['screen_name'].'/status/'.$tweet['id_str'];
```

Comment: Thanks crawf, this must be pretty close to the solution.. But the result is still the same. It seems the conversion to float, has already happened before that line, so after grabbing it out of the db.. Not sure where this happens though.

Comment: Hmm - are you able to do a `var_dump($tweet['id']);` around line 46? And that still prints out the float value?

Comment: Actually - just updated my answer using an existing field in that `$tweet` array!

Comment: great, now it's working perfectly. Can you tell me where you found this id_str existence? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Awesome! I basically just used `var_dump($tweet)` to see what the object was containing. It has a `id` and `id_str` attribute, among many other things.

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone else is having this issue; using the `id_str` instead of `id` also works to fix this this issue on the front-end templates.